# How do I fix C# Generics Compiler Error CS0311

Tags: c#, generics

I have exactly the same error as shown here, but I don't know how to fix it. Can anyone tell me how to do it?

(I think class B inherit from C. In my code its the case, it still gives this error).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384252.aspx

```
// cs0311.cs
class B{}
class C{}
class Test<T> where T : C
{ }

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Test<B> test = new Test<B>(); //CS0311
    }
}
```

---

EDIT:
My code is asp.net entity framework data access unit of work. it looks like the following. It gives Error CS0311 when I run it in unit test project, but I later when I run it in web application, I found it works fine!! What is the problem here?

```
public class DbContext
{
}


public partial class CAREContext : DbContext
{
}

public interface IUnitOfWork<TContext> : IDisposable where TContext : DbContext
{
    void Dispose();
}

public class UnitOfWork<TContext> : IUnitOfWork<TContext> where TContext : DbContext
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        UnitOfWork<CAREContext> unitOfWorkCare = new UnitOfWork<CAREContext>();
    }
}
```

Comment: `class B:C{}` fixes your problem. Your actual code must have a different problem. The statement "I think class B inherit from C" can not be true in the context of your actual code.

Comment: For your edit, the problem is likely related to the `partial` keyword and the other half of the class, generated by ASP.NET.

Comment: Ben: are you saying unit test project doesn't understand this partial keyword?

Comment: If you post the exact error message the problem will be more clear

Answer (score 3):

The class `B` does not inherit from class `C`.

Switch your `B` class to inherit from the `C` class and this should work fine.

```
class B : C { }
class C { }
class Test<T> where T : C
{ }

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Test<B> test = new Test<B>(); //CS0311
    }
}
```